# Alert aparecer apenas 1x dentro de um for

Tags: java, joptionpane

Tenho uma dúvida:

Tenho um metodo que percorre uma lista de clientes e nele verifica se ele e do tipo contaSolidaria =3 , toda vez que o metodo percorre essa lista ele da um alert mostrando um ao usuario com um joptionpane que ele e solidario.

Gostaria de saber como fazer para esse mesmo metodo percorre a lista mas apenas mostrar uma vez ao usuario essa mensagem apenas uma vez, assim que ele percorresse a lista.

```
private static final short SOLIDARIA = (short) 3;

clienteController = new ClienteController(session);

        List<ContaCorrenteModel> contaCorrenteModelList = new ArrayList<ContaCorrenteModel>();

        contaCorrenteModelList = clienteController.teste(Short.valueOf(Short.parseShort(banco)),
        Short.valueOf(Short.parseShort(agencia)), Long.valueOf(Long.parseLong(conta)));

        for (ContaCorrenteModel contaCorrenteModel : contaCorrenteModelList) {
            if (contaCorrenteModel.getNrSequNatzCnta().getCdNatzCnta() == SOLIDARIA) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "A CONTA E TIPO 3");
            }

        }

    }
```

Apenas limitar para o JOPTIONPANE. aperecer uma vez , alguem teria alguma ideia de como fazer isso?

Comment: Por favor, forneçca um **[mcve]** para que possamos testar o código e propor uma solucao.

Comment: Esse código nao é executavel, tem varias libs ai q nao fazem parte do java

Answer (score 1):

Tente fazer desta forma:

```
clienteController = new ClienteController(session);
int contador = 0;

List<ContaCorrenteModel> contaCorrenteModelList = new ArrayList<ContaCorrenteModel>();

contaCorrenteModelList = clienteController.teste(Short.valueOf(Short.parseShort(banco)),
Short.valueOf(Short.parseShort(agencia)), Long.valueOf(Long.parseLong(conta)));

for (ContaCorrenteModel contaCorrenteModel : contaCorrenteModelList) {
    if (contaCorrenteModel.getNrSequNatzCnta().getCdNatzCnta() == SOLIDARIA) {
        contador++;
    }

}

if (contador > 0) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "A CONTA E TIPO 3");
}
```

**Solução:** Criar um contador para verificar se a conta entra na condição desejada e depois do `for` verificar se o contador é maior do que 0. Se for maior do que 0 é porque encontrou um usuário do tipo desejado.

Answer (score 1):

Use uma variável `boolean` para determinar se a mensagem ja foi mostrada ou não

```
boolean mennsagemMostrada = false;
for (ContaCorrenteModel contaCorrenteModel : contaCorrenteModelList) {
    if (contaCorrenteModel.getNrSequNatzCnta().getCdNatzCnta() == SOLIDARIA) {
        if (!mensagemMostrada) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "A CONTA E TIPO 3");
            mensagemMostrada = true;
        }
    }
}
```